# Connection refused in Pycharm while docker compose on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to docker compose in Pycharm on my Ubuntu system. It throws 'Connection Refused' error while trying to compose in Pycharm while is works fine on my terminal.
[image]

Comment: Looks like some outdated PyCharm version. Could you please install a more recent one? Btw I guess `tcp` is expected instead of `http`.